# detect Input text field not empty >> make div disappear

Tags: html, text, show-hide, input-field

I have a text input field and a div that contains an image.
I would like the image to disappear once a person starts typing in the input field.

```
<div id="writehere">
<input type="text" id="myinput">
</div>

<div id="container"> 
<div id="introimg"><img src=.../intro.png"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#myinput").keypress(function () {
            $("#container").hide();
        });
});
```

But how do you want to show the pic again?

Comment: thank you! I want it to show again either by refreshing the page, or by the click on an "info" button.